# fstrim is taking too long

Tags: ssd, trim

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10. I'm running manual SSD TRIM `fstrim -v /`, and it's added to my `/etc/rc.local`.
Recently I realized that the command is taking too long to finish execution. It finishes after I login by average 10 minutes execution. It's trimming around 37 GB of free space.

It's annoying to feel that the SSD is still busy all that time. Is this normal?

Update: The only thing that changed, is this happened among Ubuntu failing to mount encrypted swap on startup. I fixed the swap problem, but `fstrim` is still slow on startup.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `ionice` which will make fstrim yield to IO operations from other programs. I have a daily cronjob like this:

```
sudo cat /etc/cron.daily/fstrim

#!/bin/sh
ionice -c2 -n7 nice -n 19 fstrim /
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like idle ionice does anything to reduce the latency of other disk accesses in case of fstrim.